# Appending a list which refers to a list inside a function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, blackjack

I have the task of producing a Blackjack game in Python which allows up to 4 human players to play plus the automated House.

I have to use a function 'get_deck' (see code below).
I am struggling to figure out how to get a card from 'get_deck' and append it to the player's list.
I managed to make the program when using my own defined list for the cards but for this assignment I have to use the 'get_deck' function. The '?????' in the below code are where I referenced my first card values list.

Here is my code:

```
def get_deck():
 deck = [value + suit for value in '23456789TJQKA' for suit in 'SHDC']
 random.shuffle(deck)
 return iter(deck)

while True:
 get_deck()  
 player1 = []
 player2 = []
 player3 = []
 player4 = []
 house = []  
 player1.append(random.choice(?????))  
 player2.append(random.choice(?????))
 player3.append(random.choice(?????))
 player4.append(random.choice(?????))
 house.append(random.choice(?????))
 player1_bust = False
 player2_bust = False
 player3_bust = False
 player4_bust = False
 house_bust = False  
 if number_players[0] == 1:  
    player1_total = total(player1)
    while True:
        player1_total = total(player1)
        print "Player 1 has these cards %s with a total value of %d." % (player1, player1_total)
        if player1_total > 21:
            print "Bust!"
            player1_bust = True
            break
        elif player1_total == 21:
            print "Blackjack!"
            break
        else:
            hit_stand = raw_input("Hit or Stand? (h or s): ").lower()
            if 'h' in hit_stand:
                player1.append(random.choice(?????))
            else:
                break
```

I hope this makes sense! Thanks in advance.

Using Python 2.7

Comment: For this assignment? So this is homework?

Comment: More like a challenge I've been set by a group of colleagues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_deck` function is already randomly shuffling the deck for you. You don't need to get random elements from its list, because it's already randomized. Just get the next element from the iterator that `get_deck` returns.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

Comment: Do you know how I would split '4D', for example, into a number and a letter, and then sum the total numbers?

Comment: @lordhazra that question is a bit too large to be asked or answered in a comment, I think. Take a look at string operations in the Python docs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm pretty much there now :-)